# $c_{00}$ and the $\ell^2$-norm

Tags: sequences-and-series, lp-spaces

Assume that we have a sequence of complex numbers $\alpha=(\alpha_k)_k\in\ell^\infty$.

Since $(\ell^2)^*=\ell^2$, we know that 
$$\sup_{\|\beta\|_2=1}=|\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle|=\|\alpha\|_2,$$
where $\|\alpha\|_2=(\sum_k|\alpha_k|^2)^{1/2}$ and $\langle{\alpha,\beta}\rangle=\sum_k\alpha_k\overline{\beta_k}$.

The question is the following: if we have that 
$$\displaystyle\sup_{\substack{\|\beta\|_2=1\\\beta\in c_{00}}}=|\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle|=C<\infty,$$

where $c_{00}$ is the space of complex sequences with finite support, can we say that $C=\|\alpha\|_2$?
Do we need any assumption on $\alpha$ for it?

---

***Possible answer***:

Clearly, $C\leq\|\alpha\|_2$ since $c_{00}\subset\ell^2$.

On the other hand, to see that $\|\alpha\|_2\leq  C$, I think about using the density of $c_{00}$ in $\ell^2$ and triangle inequality as follows:

By density, for each $\beta\in\ell^2$ we can find $\gamma_\beta\in c_{00}$ such that $\|\beta-\gamma_{\beta}\|_2<\varepsilon$.  Now,

$$|\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle|\leq|\langle \alpha,\beta-\gamma_\beta\rangle| + |\langle \alpha,\gamma_\beta\rangle|.$$

but to ensure that the first term on the rhs is small and take supremums on beta after, don't you have to assume that $\alpha\in\ell^2$ from the start?

We try to circunvent that by taking the truncated sequences $\alpha^{k)}:=(\alpha_j)_{j=1}^k$. Now

$$|\langle \alpha^{k)},\beta\rangle|\leq|\langle  \alpha^{k)},\beta-\gamma_\beta\rangle| + |\langle \alpha^{k)},\gamma_\beta\rangle|\leq \| \alpha^{k)}\|_2\|\beta-\gamma_\beta\|_2 + |\langle \alpha^{k)},\gamma_\beta\rangle|,$$

Therefore

$$|\langle \alpha^{k)},\beta\rangle|-\varepsilon\cdot\| \alpha^{k)}\|_2\leq |\langle \alpha^{k)},\gamma_\beta\rangle|.$$

Now taking limits on k and supremums on $\beta$, we conclude that

$$(1-\varepsilon)\|\alpha\|_2\leq C,$$

so $\|\alpha\|_2\leq C$.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and this is one of the most common technical issues that one runs into in Analysis. For this particular case, truncate your sequence by declaring it zero for indices bigger than $k$, say. Argue for this sequences $\alpha_k$ and then pass to the limit.

Comment: Could you detail that a bit? It seems that argument still ends up needing that $lim_{K\to\infty}\sum_{j=K}|\alpha_j|^2=0$ when doing Cauchy-Schwarz and passing to the limit for that first term on the rhs.

Comment: @Jose27 I edited the question with a possible solution based on your suggestion, I hope it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The norm of continuous linear operator can always be estimated on a dense subspace. Since $c_{00}$ is a dense subspace of $\ell^2$ it follows that $\sup\limits_{||\beta||_2=1, \text{ }\beta\in c_{00}}|\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle|=\|\alpha\|_2$.

Comment: Use `\|` rather than `||` to get norm-bars that are formatted correctly

Comment: Oh no, now I also need to re-edit my entire master thesis....

Comment: @J ctl+f is your friend, good luck. If you're feeling brave, you could try using a python script

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Added an edit on where my particular doubt was.